# Add new assignees to existing task using workflow

Tags: workflow, tasks

How do I add an assignee to a list of assignees on an existing task using a workflow?

This question breaks down to, how can I get the users currently in the assignee field, combine them with the users I want to add and assign all of that back to the assignee field in a format it will accept.

---

**EDIT:** This originally included a lot of specific information about my troubleshooting and what I was specifically trying to accomplish. Edited for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its part of the edit but I'm going to list the answer to my question separately.

The "Assigned To" field is looking for a string consisting of user names (minus domain) separated by semicolons (the semicolons are part of the same string, you can do the variable "As String" when assigning the value to the Assigned To field using Update List Item action.) You only want to export the names the first time because there's going to be a domain name you need to strip off. From then on, you want to maintain a string consisting of the user id's separated by semicolons in a separate field and have your process modify that string then input it to the Assigned To field.

To remove the domain part of the username, I actually had to create two fields to track this, one takes the name from the Assigned To field, and the other is a calculated field that contains the value of the string I put in my first custom field without the first five characters (the length of my domain name with backslash included), I would extract the string from the second field, add a semicolon then the new username I wanted to add, then assign that value to the Assigned To field. Then I have to tack 5 characters back onto the front of the string and assign that to the first of the two fields (because that field is always going to lop the first five characters off the front when posting to the second field). I made the mistake of tacking back on the domain name with backslash (i.e. ABCD). But that turns the field name and bracket notation into a literal, so I replaced the backslash with a space.

Thats about it. Its convoluted and ugly but it gets the job done.

(I couldn't get the substring function to work in the workflow string builder, thats why I had to use the two extra fields).